# jQuery add and remove class in a multi level list

Tags: jquery, html, list, multi-level

This is a list menu with 2 levels.

```
<ul id="mylist">
  <li class="lv1"><a class="privateMenuLinkJS">el1.1</a></li>
  <li class="lv1"><a>el1.2</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="lv2"><a class="privateMenuLinkJS">el1.2.1</a></li>
      <li class="lv2"><a class="privateMenuLinkJS">el1.2.2</a></li>
      <li class="lv2"><a class="privateMenuLinkJS">el1.2.3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="lv1"><a class="privateMenuLinkJS">el1.3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Rules:

1. Only elements  "privateMenuLinkJS" can trigger the click event.
2. Only elements level 1 (lv1) tagged must be tagged with "active".

If I click over el1.1 its parent "li" must be tagged with active and the others lv1 must have active class removed. Same for el1.2,el1.3

If I click over el1.2.1/1.2.2/1.2.3 its "lv1" grand parent "li" must be tagged with active and the others lv1 must have active class removed.

I have found this post [jQuery: Same Level remove class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21067941/jquery-same-level-remove-class) but it not fit to my needs.

I've tried parents, http://api.jquery.com/parent/, I've tried each http://api.jquery.com/each/ but it seems that each do not loops trough the list element.

This is the code I have created so far http://jsfiddle.net/45xc2j1k/

I know the algorithm could be better.

Any idea how to perform that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have over-complicated it. On click you could just remove the active class from all `li`s and apply to the parent `.lv1`.

EG:

```
$(document).on("click", ".privateMenuLinkJS", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //Remove ALL active class:
    $("#mylist .active").removeClass( "active" );
    //Add active class for is parent if it is level 1
    $( this ).parents(".lv1").addClass( "active" );    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0bnk08nq/1/ (updated)

Comment: Hi Moob, I think I must change a little bit the code. If I click over any level 2 elemets, all them becomes red. It shuld be only their grand parent li.

Comment: They all become red because they inherit their parent's style. IE if you say that an `li` is green then all the children of that `li` will also be green. You should make sure that the `ul`s have a color defined. See [my updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0bnk08nq/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery Closest: http://api.jquery.com/closest/

This will allow you to traverse up through ancestors (find parents or grandparents) by class.

The following code will remove the active class for each list item, then add the active class to the closest 'lv1' list item.

```
$('.lv1').removeClass("active");
$(this).closest('.lv1').addClass("active");
```

See this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/45xc2j1k/3/

Comment: Hi ericbell, I have tried closest to but If I click over any level 2 elemets, all them becomes red. It shuld be only their grand parent li.